# Where CERTENCODED can be used?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can anyone give live example of CERTENCODED? I am not able to understand CERTENCODED function's purpose though I have read about it.

Comment: I know nothing about this function, but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510218.aspx) has two examples. Can you be more precise about what you're trying to do with the function and what you don't understand? And note that it exists in SQL Server 2012 only, but your question is tagged SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns all public data of the certificate in the same binary .DEM format you'd get using the BACKUP CERTIFICATE statement:

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE cert1
      ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'
      WITH SUBJECT = 'My test cert';

backup certificate cert1 to file = 'cert1.cer'

select CERTENCODED(CERT_ID('cert1'))
select * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'c:/.../cert1.cer', SINGLE_BLOB) rs;
```

You should see that the two string of data returned by the SELECTs are identical.

You can then transfer the blob to another database and create a new certificate from it ("CREATE CERTIFICATE ... FROM BINARY = 0x", so you'll be able to encode data with one certificate and decode with the other.  Consider this function as another way to preserve the certificate, but without using the file system.

Very similarly, you can obtain the private key from the certificate using CERTPRIVATEKEY(...), then use to create a compatible certificate in another database.